# How to understand if your application has finished computing in a multithreading consumer-producer scenario in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, producer-consumer

I'm trying my hand at multithreading in java, something I have never done before. The pet application I'm trying to design at the moment has one Blocking Queue and several Workers. The application follows these rules:

- A worker waits for a message in the queue
- When a worker gets a message from the queue, it processes it, and may produce more messages that are added back to the queue.
- Some messages don't generate more messages.
- The application is started with several messages in the queue.
- 1 Worker = 1 Thread

The application is supposed to exit if:

- There are no more messages on the queue
- All workers are blocked and waiting for a message to be consumed

Basically, once all messages are consumed and no more messages are being produced/present in the system, I'm expected to exit. The application is guaranteed to reach this point eventually.

Now my question, I'm not sure what's the best practice/design to understand when the above conditions are true avoiding racing conditions. Any help?

I'm currently at design stage, so I don't have code to show you, sorry about that (I know my question at this point is quite generic, so feel free to ask me any question). Any advice is welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your expressed design appears to have "workers" that act as producers, consumers and sometimes both. How does a worker know that there are no more messages needing to be produced when some consumed messages result in new messages in the queue?

Comment: @JimRogers Yes you are correct. In most cases my workers act as both producers and consumers. You can imagine I'm designing a graph explorer, basically using BSF. I keep up a synchronized set of the the nodes already visited. Hope this makes sense. I know usually you want to keep producers and consumers separate, but in this simple case it felt like over engineering. If separating them would solve my problem though, I'm super happy to do so.

Comment: There seem to be two kinds of messages. One kind can simply be consumed, while the other needs to be consumed and then the resulting additional messages need to be placed in a queue. Is it possible to separate the two kinds of messages into different queues? One set of workers can process the simple messages and another distinct set of workers can process the messages which result in additional messages. This allows the workers processing the complex messages to feed the queue read by workers only processing simple messages. Empty queues mean stop.

Comment: The messages are of the same kind, you don't know if they create more messages until you take them and process them unfortunately. If I understand your solution correctly, I think you still retain the problems I'm facing. Checking the queue size is not enough. Even if the queue is empty now, a worker could be processing a message that is creating more messages. In theory, the system is done when a) the queue is empty b) no workers are processing messages, problem is, I can't find a way to do all this checks atomically in one go. I see all sort of nasty racing conditions.

Comment: There must be some criteria for deciding if a message results in more messages. First scan the messages in a queue to identify such messages, transfer those messages to another queue, then place the generated messages in the simple message queue and process those. If all the message generating messages are processed first you then only need to process the simple messages.

Comment: There are criteria, but you don't know until you process the message. What I'm writing is a web crawler, and the messages are URLs. Until I get the message off the queue and process it (get the relative page, and extract all the links), I don't know if the message will generate other URLs, and by this point, it's pointless to requeue the message. But even if this were not the case, your idea would not work anyway. Even if you process the simple messages first, the "other" messages can still generate more messages. The new messages can then create or not create new messages.

Comment: [continue] On top of this, you cannot rely only on checking the length of the queue, because while you check the queue, there might be a worker processing a message that will create more messages. The only way I can see of checking and deciding that the system is exhausted is to check the queue AND checking that the workers are not processing any message. The problem is, I can't find an atomic way of doing this.

Comment: Have a worker thread increment a shared counter while it is processing a message  and decrement the counter when it is done processing the message. If the shared counter is 0 and the queue length is 0 then your processing is complete.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be for each worker to add 1 to an AtomicInteger when it starts (representing that it is working) and then subtract 1 when it ends.   After it subtracts 1, if the AtomicInteger is 0, this means that there are no “active” workers.

So when a worker ends, it will Subtract 1 from the atomicInteger and then check If the queue size is zero (no waiting messages) and the atomic integer is zero (no active workers), you can quit the application.

Comment: I see. I assume this should live in it's own Monitoring object (written by me), is it correct? I can do this. I was curious if there is a more out of the box tool in Java to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: This might not work under race condition. 
It's possible that an active worker A add some messages into the queue and end,
after another worker B checked *the queue is empty*, but before worker B checks if *no active workers*,